# highcharts 7 issue with negative ticks

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts upgrade from version 5 to version 7 is causing negative ticks on x and y axes even when no negative data exists. Various chart plots are wrongly displaying negative axes. Instead the expectation is that the axes must start at 0 (min: 0 is given) and must plot only the positive ticks (tickAmount: 5 is given).

This worked perfectly with version 5 but is behaving weird with version 7.
[image]

The left picture is version 7 chart. Look at the starting tick, -2.5, whereas there are no negative values, so it must start at 0. Also observe the last tick is not appropriate width as the other tick intervals and ends abruptly in between.

Here is the link for demonstration of the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/3awvyn0b/3/, see config for x-axis which is not being reflected in the plot:

```
xAxis: {
        tickAmount: 5,
        min: 0
    },
```

If I remove tickAmount for the x-axis, the negative ticks are resolved but then the ticks are not correctly marked.
[image]

What has changed in version 7 that I need to handle?

Comment: Hi @shweta, That problem looks like a regression bug. You can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek, I just did - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13749#issue-641882231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a regression issue (bug report here: [github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13749#issue-641882231](http://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13749#issue-641882231)), the suggested workaround for now is to either

1. use **even number of ticks** on the chart. So instead of using `tickAmount: 5` I'm now using `tickAmount: 6` and that has resolved the negative ticks issue.
2. or along with the tickAmount (either odd or even tick number, as the need maybe) set **`endOnTick: true`** for the xAxis